# Exception when reading file image on server - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

i hope anyone help me in this problem ..

i have simple aspx code to get image file from directory and make some proccesses on it as drawing somthing on it after that i save it on the same directory.

really the code has worked well on local machine, but on server side the code fails and the exception appears. **( ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid )**

**please look at the code :**

```
DirectoryInfo[] dir = new DirectoryInfo[2];
dir[0] = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Image/DB/Large/"));
dir[1] = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Image/DB/Thumb/"));

System.Drawing.Image signature = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("Image/Design/signature.png"));
for (int i = 0; i < dir.Length; i++)
{
    FileInfo[] fs = dir[i].GetFiles("*.jpg");
    foreach (FileInfo s in fs)
    {
        FileStream strm = s.OpenRead();
        String name = s.Name;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawImage(signature, new Point(0, 0));       
        strm.Close();
        if (i == 0)
        {
            String v = Server.MapPath("Image/DB/Large/" + name);
            img.Save(v);
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            String v = Server.MapPath("Image/DB/Slide/" + name);
            img.Save(v);
        }
        g.Dispose();         
    }
}
```

**Exception Details :**

Parameter is not valid.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

```
  Source Error:

  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

  Stack Trace:


[ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
   System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData) +1062843
   System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream) +8
   Developer.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +279
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Answer (score 3):

You must convert your FileStream to Stream

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(..);// This method take Stream as argument and nor FileStream
```

You can try with CopyTo, in order to convert.

Link  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx

```
FileStream strm = s.OpenRead();
Stream stream = new Stream();
strm.CopyTo(stream);
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Before .Net 4, you can use this extension method

public static class Ext
{

```
public static void CopyTo(this FileStream in, Stream out)
{
    byte[] temp= new byte[16*1024]; //You can adjust this value
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = in.Read(temp,0, temp.Length)) > 0)
    {
        out.Write(temp, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks Aghilas Yakoub.. but i using .net 3.5 .. is there any other way to do it that.

Comment: I do the next code to be as below, but is still to be Exception .. i don't know why !! ?
 

    `FileStream strm = s.OpenRead();
    String name = s.Name;
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    CopyTo(strm, stream);
    System.Drawing.Image img =    System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);`